# Where does the $\pi$ comes from?

Tags: definite-integrals

I have calculated with Mathematica the integral:

$$\int_{-h/2}^{h/2}dz\int_{-R}^{R}dx\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}dy(x^2+z^2)$$

the result is: $$\dfrac{\pi}{12}h^3R^2+\dfrac{\pi}{4}hR^4$$

I am surprised about the $\pi$: where does it comes from?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks it was a typo. See the edit.

Comment: $\pi$ somes from the second integration because there is an $\tan^{-1}(.)$ in the antiderivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point you are integrating something like:

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx
$$

The graph of the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$  looks like this:

[image]

So you are trying to integrate (find the area) of half the circle. Of course, you would expect $\pi$.